# Reshape panda dataframe in a specific way

Tags: python, file, dataframe, reshape, transformation

I'm new in Python and I want to reshape the data structure for further analysis. I want to reshape the table so that I can only have one row for each ID. I read that some libraries can do that but I don't know how.

The code for the example attached looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [123, 123], 'Method': ['angular', 'angular'], 'Colour': ['red', 'blue'] }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['ID','Method','Colour'])
df
```

every help will be really appreciated

Thanks in advance

[Reshape_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGRXm.jpg)

Comment: The code for the example attached looks like:    The code for the example attached looks like:

import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [123, 123], 'Method': ['angular', 'angular'], 'Colour': ['red', 'blue'] }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['ID','Method','Colour'])
df

Answer (score 0):

`unstack` is your friend for this kind of reshaping. Possible code could be:

```
resul = df.reset_index().set_index(['ID', 'Method', 'index']
                                   ).unstack().reset_index()

# clean up the column names
resul.columns = [i if j == '' else i + '_' + str(j)
                 for i, j in resul.columns.tolist()]
```

It gives as expected:

```
    ID   Method Colour_0 Colour_1
0  123  angular      red     blue
```